# how to check a dropdown has a value in jquery?

Tags: jquery

what is the best way to check is a drop down contains a value which isnt null.

```
 <select class="dropinput" name="Finish1" id="dropFinish1" tabindex="10" disabled="disabled">
    <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

How to check the above drop down contains no values?

Comment: Contains no value (no <option> element without value=""), or has no value selected?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
if($('.dropinput > option[value!=""]').length == 0) {
    //dropdown contains no non-null options
}
```

This will check if the select box contains zero options that have a value different than "" (empty).

So the following HTML will be seen as empty in the above jQuery:

```
<select class="dropinput" name="Finish1" id="dropFinish1" tabindex="10" disabled="disabled">
    <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

The following HTML will **not** be seen as empty:

```
<select class="dropinput" name="Finish1" id="dropFinish1" tabindex="10" disabled="disabled">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="some value"></option>
</select>
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KLZrZ/1/)

Answer (score 2):

try this

this will give you the value only if it has a value

```
$("#dropFinish1 option:selected[value!=""]).val()
```

Comment: this works beautifully, althout there is a missing ", so it should read `$("#dropFinish1 option:selected[value!=""]").val()`

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean:

```
var hasOption = true;
$('.dropinput option').each(function(i, v){    
        var $this = $(this);        
        if($this.val() == '' || $this.size < 1) {
            hasOption = false;
        } else {
            hasOption = true;
        }        
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.dropinput').text();
```

if that returns "" it means that there is nothing selected.

```
var selectedItem = "";
$('.dropinput option').each(function(){
if($(this).attr('selected') == 'selected'){
selectedItem = $(this).val();
}
}):
```

if the variable stays empty it means that there is no item selected.